# Tengo problemas con el login de passport con express y nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, passport

Presento inconvenientes al logearme con passport

Este es mi index.js completo

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const session = require('express-session');
const validator = require('express-validator');
const passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const { database } = require('./keys');

// initializations

const app = express();
require('./lib/passport');

// settings

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'),'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'),'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: require('./lib/handlebars.js')
}));
app.set('view engine','.hbs');

// middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'faztmysqlnodemysql',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MySQLStore(database)
  }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(validator());


// global variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.message = req.flash('message');
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    app.locals.user =  req.user;
    next();
});

// routers
app.use(require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/authentication.js'));
//Administrador
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/index.js'));
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/usuarios.js'));
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/contactos.js'));
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/torre.js'));
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/parqueadero.js'))
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/visitante.js'))
app.use('/admin',require('./routes/administrador/informes.js'))
//Operario
app.use('/panel',require('./routes/operario/index.js'));
//app.use('/links',require('./routes/links.js'))

// public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
// starting the server

app.listen(app.get('port'),() => {
    console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

En este fracción de código instancia mis variables globales en el index.js que es donde creo que presenta problemas

```
// global variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.message = req.flash('message');
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    app.locals.user =  req.user;
    next();
});
```

Ahora este es mi archivo de rutas llamado authetication.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const passport = require('passport');
const { isLoggedIn, isNotLoggedIn } = require('../lib/auth');

router.get('/signup', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('auth/signup');
});
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));

router.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('auth/signin');
});
router.post('/signin', (req, res, next) =>{
    passport.authenticate('local.signin', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/signin',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    if(req.user.tipo === 1){
        res.redirect('/admin');
    }else if(req.user.tipo === 2){
        res.redirect('/panel');
    }
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect('signin');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Y este es mi archivo controlador de passport

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const pool = require('../database');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  }, async (req, username, password, done) => {
    const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username]);
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      const user = rows[0];
      const validPassword = await helpers.matchPassword(password, user.password);
      if (validPassword) {
        console.log(user);
        done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Welcome ' + user.username));
      } else {
        done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Incorrect Password'));
      }
    } else {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'The Username does not exists.'));
    }
}));

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  }, async (req, username, password, done) => {

    const { nombre, apellido, cedula, telefono } = req.body;
    const tipo = 2;
    let newUser = {
      nombre,
      apellido,
      cedula,
      telefono,
      username,
      password,
      tipo
    };
    newUser.password = await helpers.encryptPassword(password);
    // Saving in the Database
    const result = await pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ', newUser);
    newUser.id = result.insertId;
    return done(null, newUser);
  }));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]);
    done(null, rows[0]);
});
```

Dentro de `'local.signin'` Valido el usuario, esta validacion es correcta al imprimir `validPassword`.
El problema es que a pesar de que la validación es exitosa me devuelve a la vista de login, pero si tipeo la url que debería redirigir después del logeo exitoso entra si ningún problema (la vista que dirige después del logeo valida si el usuario esta logeado con `isLoggedIn`)

```
router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
   if(req.user.tipo === 1){
       res.redirect('/admin');
   }else if(req.user.tipo === 2){
       res.redirect('/panel');
   }
});
```

Este es el copido de  `isLoggedIn`

```
module.exports = {
   isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {
       if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
           return next();
       }
       return res.redirect('/signin');
   },
   isNotLoggedIn (req, res, next){
       if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
           return next();
       }
       return res.redirect('/profile');
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil, el numero de caracteres del campo contraseña es demasiado corto, por lo cual el hash no se esta guardando por completo, debes ampliar el numero de caracteres del campo password en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Si bien la respuesta proporcionada puede solucionar el problema, aportaría mucho más, que añadieses un poco de código y los resultados de manera que la respuesta sea mucho más interesante para cualquiera que lo lea, y no se considere de baja calidad. Además puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].